# how to maek it so that if a for loop ends without triggering an if statement the loop begins again (python)

Tags: python

my for loop is looping through a list and i want tomake it so that if a value a user enters a value it its is not found in the list iwant to get another value from the user to check for in the list

```
import datetime as date
x = date.datetime.now()
D = []
d = int((x.strftime("%d")))
M = (x.strftime("%B"))
for i in range(1,8):
d = d + 1D.append(d)
print (M+", "+str(d))
z = str(input("enter date for booking"))
for i in D :
    if i == z:
        break
```

Comment: check out the `else` clause that `for` supports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
  
  x = int(input("Enter a Value : "))
  if x not in list:
    print("Try again") 
    continue
  print("Whatever you want to print")
  break
```

This could help you with your project. If the variables are integers, keep it as int but you could switch it to str or float according with your variable types.